# Responsive site built with skel framework fails to apply css only when using pretty URLs

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, skel

I am using a template (html5up.net/prologue) for a responsive site which uses the skel framework.

The site works perfectly fine except when I access it through a pretty URL. Example: example.com/fake-dir/. The dir fake-dir does not exist and pretty URLS make the webserver look in the root directory. For some reason, the css style is not applied when using pretty URLS. My .htaccess which applies the prety urls is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]
```

I have tracked down the problem to init.js and have a feeling it has to do with how js is trying to apply a css file. I think it is looking for a css file in the pretty url directory/css insted of the root directory/css. I have tried adding in an absolute path at the begining of init.js as shown here for the different styles but that did not work. 'global': { range: '*', href: 'example.com/css/style.css', containers: 1400, grid: { gutters: 40 }, viewport: { scalable: false } },

Here is the entire init.js file. Any help is appriciated.

```
/*
Prologue by HTML5 UP
html5up.net | @n33co
Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
*/

(function($) {

    skel.init({
        reset: 'full',
        breakpoints: {
            'global': { range: '*', href: 'css/style.css', containers: 1400, grid: { gutters: 40 }, viewport: { scalable: false } },
            'wide': { range: '961-1880', href: 'css/style-wide.css', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
            'normal': { range: '961-1620', href: 'css/style-normal.css', containers: 960, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
            'narrow': { range: '961-1320', href: 'css/style-narrow.css', containers: '100%', grid: { gutters: 20 } },
            'narrower': { range: '-960', href: 'css/style-narrower.css', containers: '100%', grid: { gutters: 20 } },
            'mobile': { range: '-736', href: 'css/style-mobile.css', containers: '100%!', grid: { collapse: true } }
        },
        plugins: {
            layers: {
                config: {
                    mode: 'transform'
                },
                sidePanel: {
                    hidden: true,
                    breakpoints: 'narrower',
                    position: 'top-left',
                    side: 'left',
                    animation: 'pushX',
                    width: 240,
                    height: '100%',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    html: '<div data-action="moveElement" data-args="header"></div>',
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                },
                sidePanelToggle: {
                    breakpoints: 'narrower',
                    position: 'top-left',
                    side: 'top',
                    height: '4em',
                    width: '5em',
                    html: '<div data-action="toggleLayer" data-args="sidePanel" class="toggle"></div>'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $(function() {

        var $window = $(window),
            $body = $('body');

        // Disable animations/transitions until the page has loaded.
            $body.addClass('is-loading');

            $window.on('load', function() {
                $body.removeClass('is-loading');
            });

        // CSS polyfills (IE<9).
            if (skel.vars.IEVersion < 9)
                $(':last-child').addClass('last-child');

        // Forms (IE<10).
            var $form = $('form');
            if ($form.length > 0) {

                $form.find('.form-button-submit')
                    .on('click', function() {
                        $(this).parents('form').submit();
                        return false;
                    });

                if (skel.vars.IEVersion < 10) {
                    $.fn.n33_formerize=function(){var _fakes=new Array(),_form = $(this);_form.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.val() == '' || e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } }).blur(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) return; if (e.val() == '') { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } }).focus(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) return; if (e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(''); } }); _form.find('input[type=password]').each(function() { var e = $(this); var x = $($('<div>').append(e.clone()).remove().html().replace(/type="password"/i, 'type="text"').replace(/type=password/i, 'type=text')); if (e.attr('id') != '') x.attr('id', e.attr('id') + '_fakeformerizefield'); if (e.attr('name') != '') x.attr('name', e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield'); x.addClass('formerize-placeholder').val(x.attr('placeholder')).insertAfter(e); if (e.val() == '') e.hide(); else x.hide(); e.blur(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var e = $(this); var x = e.parent().find('input[name=' + e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield]'); if (e.val() == '') { e.hide(); x.show(); } }); x.focus(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var x = $(this); var e = x.parent().find('input[name=' + x.attr('name').replace('_fakeformerizefield', '') + ']'); x.hide(); e.show().focus(); }); x.keypress(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); x.val(''); }); });  _form.submit(function() { $(this).find('input[type=text],input[type=password],textarea').each(function(event) { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) e.attr('name', ''); if (e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(''); } }); }).bind("reset", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); $(this).find('select').val($('option:first').val()); $(this).find('input,textarea').each(function() { var e = $(this); var x; e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); switch (this.type) { case 'submit': case 'reset': break; case 'password': e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); x = e.parent().find('input[name=' + e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield]'); if (e.val() == '') { e.hide(); x.show(); } else { e.show(); x.hide(); } break; case 'checkbox': case 'radio': e.attr('checked', e.attr('defaultValue')); break; case 'text': case 'textarea': e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); if (e.val() == '') { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } break; default: e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); break; } }); window.setTimeout(function() { for (x in _fakes) _fakes[x].trigger('formerize_sync'); }, 10); }); return _form; };
                    $form.n33_formerize();
                }

            }

        // Scrolly links.
            $('.scrolly').scrolly();

        // Nav.
            var $nav_a = $('#nav a');

            // Scrolly-fy links.
                $nav_a
                    .scrolly()
                    .on('click', function(e) {

                        var t = $(this),
                            href = t.attr('href');

                        if (href[0] != '#')
                            return;

                        e.preventDefault();

                        // Clear active and lock scrollzer until scrolling has stopped
                            $nav_a
                                .removeClass('active')
                                .addClass('scrollzer-locked');

                        // Set this link to active
                            t.addClass('active');

                    });

            // Initialize scrollzer.
                var ids = [];

                $nav_a.each(function() {

                    var href = $(this).attr('href');
                    if (href[0] != '#')
                        return;

                    ids.push(href.substring(1));

                });

                $.scrollzer(ids, { pad: 200, lastHack: true });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not a problem with the template or js. It was how I was calling the js files in the frst place. I was not using the an absolute path